# JavaFX Virtual keyboard blink

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, touch, monocle

I develop an embedded JavaFX app for touch screen.

I have a problem with JavaFX vitrual keyboard. When it's displayed, the screen blink  (more specially, it blink from keyboard to app quickly).

I run my application with this command line :

```
sudo java -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dembedded=monocle -Dprism.verbose=true -Dglass.platform=Monocle \
 -Djavafx.platform=eglfb -jar --module-path /home/pi/armv6hf-sdk/lib \
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics \ 
--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED \ 
--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections=ALL-UNNAMED \ 
--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED \ 
--illegal-access=warn app.jar
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, thanks to Gluon support, is to set `-Duse.egl=true`.